# JavaScript: Output results to multiple fields with different names

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

this is my first post on StackOverflow,
I have read a lot of pages regarding code snippets on this website, and always you give good answers and advice..

Now however I am in need in some assistance..
I want to populate more than one input field, I tried adding a field ID in the JavaScript, but so far no luck.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function calculateAge(inputFieldId, outputFieldId, alert_18){

var age;

var input = document.getElementById(inputFieldId).value;

// Past date info

var pyear = parseInt(input.substring(6,10));
var pmonth = parseInt(input.substring(0,2)) - 1;
var pday = parseInt(input.substring(3,5));
// Today info
today = new Date();
year = today.getFullYear() ;
month = today.getMonth();
day = today.getDate();

if ( month < pmonth ){
age = year - pyear - 1;
}
else if ( month > pmonth ){
age = year - pyear;
}
else if ( month == pmonth ){
if ( day < pday ){
age = year - pyear - 1;
}
else if ( day > pday ){
age = year - pyear;
}
else if ( day == pday ){
age = year - pyear;
}
}
document.getElementById(outputFieldId).value = age;
document.getElementById(outputFieldId).value = age2;

if(alert_18 == 'true'){
if(age < 18){

//Customize alert message

alert('Attention: under 18!');
}
}
}
//-->
</script>
```

Any help would greatly appreciated

Comment: okay make it clear what do you want. A more details. perhaps you can edit your code and add there html portion also

Comment: At the present moment I am able to populate 1 input field with the result given by age, but I want to populate more than 1 input field so the user doesn't have to enter it 3 times.

Comment: Seems to me your are overwriting the first assignment to outputField with age2 (where did that come from btw?).
If you want to populate more fields then you have to supply more fieldids to your function or have some namingconvention in place your function can use to assign the value to the different fields...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following solution to handle population to an arbitrary number of outputfields (and roughly calculating age - not considering leapyears):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function calculateAge(inputFieldId, outputFieldId, alert_18){
  var input = document.getElementById(inputFieldId).value,
      pyear = parseInt(input.substring(6,10)),
      pmonth = parseInt(input.substring(0,2)) - 1,
      pday = parseInt(input.substring(3,5)),
      dt1 = new Date(),
      dt2 = new Date(pyear, pmonth, pday),
      ageMs = dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime(),
      age = parseInt(ageMs / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365);


  if(outputFieldId instanceof Array) {
    for(var i = 0, l = outputFieldId.length; i < l; i++)
      document.getElementById(outputFieldId[i]).value = age;
  }
  else
    document.getElementById(outputFieldId).value = age; 

  if(alert_18 && age < 18) {
    //Customize alert message

    alert('Attention: under 18!');
  }
}
//-->
</script>
```

Then when you call it you could either pass a single string as outputfieldid like so:

```
calculateAge("get-age", "calculated-age", true);
```

or your could pass an array of fieldids like so:

```
calculateAge("get-age", ["calculated-age1", "calculated-age2"], true);
```

Comment: Long overdue response, but thank you so much for answering in the way you did, I tested it, and it's working good :)